# Why can't I install any gems on my Mac?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I tried doing `gem install` for just about any gem and I have been getting errors. I think I need to reset and or update something on my computer but not sure what.

Here is some of the command line code errors:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'multi_json' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://s3.amazonaws.com/production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)

ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'cowsay' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://s3.amazonaws.com/production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)

sudo gem install rubygems-update
Password:
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rubygems-update' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://s3.amazonaws.com/production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

Does anyone know what I need to do to fix this? I got a new computer and was wondering if I need to set up the user differently or something?

Comment: +1 Because I have seen countless Github issue reports on gems without people realizing that it has nothing to do with the Gems but rather the server pushing the gems.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I had the same problem and this solution from above user worked for me.

```
rvm osx-ssl-certs update all
```

Answer (score 9):

There seems to be this common issue lately. If you're on a Mac, try doing this if you installed via RVM:

```
rvm osx-ssl-certs update all
```

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively you can add the insecure ruby source with the following command:

```
sudo gem sources -a http://rubygems.org
```

Answer (score 5):

For those that arent using rvm, but are using homebrew:

```
brew tap raggi/ale
brew install openssl-osx-ca
```

This worked for me.